# iphone - image loading

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Hi I have been having problems loading images quickly to the screen. There seems to be a delay the first time I hit the view:

Here is how I load the images:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Hole%d_", courseName, i]];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    frame.origin.x = cx;
    imageView.frame = frame;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
    imageView = nil;
}
```

Each image is 640 x 820.

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect loading 19 640x820 images to take a little while when hitting your view? Also, I'd be concerned about the memory usage of all of these images. Have you thought about lazy-loading images only as they're needed onscreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much else you could do to speed this up.

However, you do have a memory management issue which could speed up the process to some extent.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)     {
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Hole%d_", courseName, i]];
     imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
     frame.origin.x = cx;
     imageView.frame = frame;
     [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
     cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
     [imageView release];
 }
```

Comment: If the OP is using ARC, then calling `release` is an error and the original code was fine with respect to memory management.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted you are encountering a fundamental problem of image processing: the finite I/O speed of the device.

Incidentally, `imagedNamed:` internally caches images, which probably explains why subsequent loads are fast.

If tiling is not an option (as @Krio recommended), you could try preloading the images into cache on a background thread before your view is needed. For example, if this view is commonly accesses from another view, you could start a series of `imageNamed:` calls wrapped in `dispatch_async` or an `NSOperationQueue` when the earlier view loads. This would only help in a certain set of circumstances, though:

-You know that your image view is almost always the next UI element to be requested.

-You know in advance which assets are to be loaded.

-Your set of images is small enough that you aren't going to fill up all the memory, forcing the frameworks to evict the cache you just filled

Note that this also introduces a fair amount of complexity to your application design, so should best be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, loading images takes some time. You have big amount of big images, so it is expected result.
Try to think about tiled layer instead of adding UIImages to scroll view.
CATiledLayer may help you

Comment: any examples that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Image loading freezes UI. You can do this task in background so that UI never friezed. Try the code below.

```
  -(void)loadImages{
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImagesInBackGround) withObject:nil];
   } 

  -(void)loadImagesInBackGround{

        for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
  {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_Hole%d_", courseName, i]];
       imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
       frame.origin.x = cx;
       imageView.frame = frame;
       [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
       cx += scrollView.frame.size.width;
       imageView = nil;
  }

}
```

You should call loadImages: from where you are going to load images. Alternately you can try Grand Central Dipatch (GCD) to load images in back ground.